# Python/Django development, windows or linux?

Tags: python, windows, django, linux

I have been working on Python quite a lot recently and started reading the doc for Django, however I can't deny the fact that most of the video tutorials I find usually shows Linux as the chosen OS. I've ignored this mostly, but I started to come upon some problems with people using commands such as "touch" for which I have no idea about what the equivalent is in the Windows 7 command prompt. I've heard about New-Item in Power Shell, however it's messy and I am fearing that this "equivalent hunt" might come again and again...

So I started to wonder why were most of the people using Linux with Python, would be a good move (knowing that my Linux knowledge is completely null) to learn to use Linux for development purpose? Would it allow me to be more efficient at developing with Python in general? Would it be possible to list the benefits of doing so?

Comment: A better place for this question is: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I used Windows for quite some time for Django development, but finally figured out that Linux is simply the better way to go. Here are some reasons why:

- some Python packages can not be installed at all or correctly in Windows OR it will create a lot of hassle for you to do so
- if you need to deploy your Django app it makes more sense to use a Unix-flavored system, simply because its 99% likely that you deployment environment is the same. Doing a dry run on your local machine with the same configuration will save you a lot of time later on + here you are "allowed" to make mistakes.
- If your apps gets complex its way easier in Linux to get the required dependencies, be it extensions, libraries, etc.. In Windows you end up looking for the right site to download everything and go through some hassle of installation and configuration. It took me lots of time to just search for some specific things sometimes. In Linux its often just an "apt-get" (or similiar) and you are done.
- Did I mention that everything is faster to get and install in Linux?

Of course if your app is simple and you don't need to care about the deployment then Windows is fine.

Comment: I agree with you that Linux is much developer friendly, but I want to shift to windows 10 for Python Django, windows have introduced 
"Power shell" will it make difference ? One main reason for moving to windows is Community edition of Visual Studio and Azure platform. But I still wonder will the development be as smooth as Linux over there ?

Comment: I can't really answer you there, but powershell is not the same as a linux terminal. From what I heard its not replaceable. You still have the problems I mentioned above (independent of which terminal you use). In the end you can try it out of course.

Comment: I think the point about deployment is understated. If you plan to deploy your app on Windows, then, by all means, use Windows to develop. If you plan to deploy it on Linux, use Linux or at least a flavor of UNIX for local development. This helps you tackle any platform-specific dependency issues early rather than late, and reduces the possibility of platform-specific bugs popping up in QA or production when they will be more expensive to fix.

Comment: If you have full control over where your app is deployed then yes. In most cases you are an employee of a company and most of them deploy Python based apps in a Linux-like system.

Answer (score 8):

Although there are some benefits in using Linux for Python development (for example, some libraries only work on Linux); there is nothing stopping you from using Windows for *django* work; I use it everyday and nothing has yet to crop up.

The right IDE that you are comfortable with will go a long way towards making your development experience more enjoyable. Many people use [Pydev](http://pydev.org) with Eclipse; but I prefer [PyCharm](http://jetbrains.com/pycharm)

A lot of the tutorials will show you a Linux or Mac desktop (and shell) and you can get the equivalent commands (like `touch`, `ls` and others) by installing [`unixtools`](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/) - which are native versions of common unix tools.

You should bookmark [this website](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) which has Windows installers for common Python libraries.

Answer (score 2):

It depends what operating system do you like most. 
You could use Aptana 3 with pydev(included) for development.

When developing remember about use of "os" python lib for paths to dirs, so your application will work correctly under windows and linux.

For example:

```
PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'site_media')
```

Answer (score 1):

django is written in pure python, so using Windows + Eclipse + PyDev for development is enough.

if you really want to follow the cool guys using some Linux commands, then have [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) or [mingWin](http://www.mingw.org/) installed and set the system PATH to BIN directive. Then, you could use them (include your **touch**).

Linux is best choice for deployment of a django project, where you can easily compile / install / configure some cool things like nginx, uWSGI, mod_wsgi, Apache2, and many many useful Python C extensions.

Another reason for using Linux, is that virtual private servers, which are used to host projects, are more likely to support it.

Answer (score 1):

I normally use OSX on my desktop, but I use Linux for Python because that's how it will get deployed.  Specifically, I use Ubuntu Desktop in a virtual machine to develop Python applications and I use Ubuntu on the server to deploy them.  This means that my understanding of library and module requirements/dependencies are 100% transferrable to the server when I'm ready to deploy the application.

If I used OSX (or Windows) to develop Python apps I would have to deal with two different methods of handling requirements and dependencies --- it's just too much work.

My suggestion:  use VMWare Player (it's free) and find a Ubuntu VM to start learning.  It's not too complicated and is actually quite fun.